# Circumvent interaction between memoir and mdframed

Tags: mdframed, double-sided

I noticed that when I use `mdframed` in a `memoir` document I'm not able to change the margin lengths of any frame defined from `mdframed`. This appears to happen regardless of the place where I try to set their lengths.

Here is a MWE showing the problem.

```tex
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\definecolor{creamy}{HTML}{e2bf40}
\colorlet{callout-bg}{creamy!50}

\newmdenv[backgroundcolor=callout-bg]{newframed}

\begin{document}
    \begin{newframed}[leftmargin=-10pt, rightmargin=10pt]
        The leftmargin is \the\mdflength{leftmargin}. The rightmargin is \the\mdflength{rightmargin}.
    \end{newframed}
\end{document}
```

[image: The actual used value is always 0.0pt]

Is there a way to circumvent this unwanted interaction?

Comment: use tcolorbox instead of mdframed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I need to be able to use colored framed paragraphs that can span multiple pages. Does `tcolorbox` allow for this usecase?

Comment: @araruna that and much much more. IMO there isn't much reason to use mdframed any more

Comment: I've removed the memoir tag

Comment: Tcolorbox offers breakable boxes,and they are much more reliable than the one of mdframed. Mdframed has various problems here, e.g it can break to early or insert unwanted space.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yeah, I'm reading the docs now and it is a beast! Thank you for pointing me to it.

Comment: This also happens if you use the `book` or `report` or `article` classes. I haven't checked any other. So your problem is with (your use of) the `mdframed` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is independent of `memoir` (the same happens with `book`). As explained in section 6.7 of the `mdframed` documentation you need the `innermargin` and `outermargin` options in two-side documents (the default mode for both `memoir` and `book`). Or alternatively you can use the `leftmargin` and `rightmargin` options but with the addition of the `usetwoside=false` option.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\definecolor{creamy}{HTML}{e2bf40}
\colorlet{callout-bg}{creamy!50}

\newmdenv[backgroundcolor=callout-bg]{newframed}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{newframed}[innermargin=-10pt,outermargin=10pt]
 The leftmargin is \the\mdflength{leftmargin}. 
 The rightmargin is \the\mdflength{rightmargin}.
\end{newframed}

\begin{newframed}[usetwoside=false,leftmargin=-10pt,rightmargin=10pt]
 The leftmargin is \the\mdflength{leftmargin}. 
 The rightmargin is \the\mdflength{rightmargin}.
\end{newframed}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This really solves the question. I saw this part on the manual and I indeed tried to use these options, but somehow they made no visual difference at first (10pt is not big enough) and I forgot to consider them in my "debug" MWE. Thank you.